# Get string value of semantic property

Tags: java, jena, protege

In my ontology I have the class called "`festival`" and it has property value called "`CRISTMAS`". It's a string type value. How can I get this value using Jena OWL API?

Comment: It would be much easier to answer this question if you show a sample of your data (just a sample please, not the whole file). For example, in RDF it would not be common for a class to have a property value: more usually, an instance of the class would have a particular value. Depending on which of these you mean, we can suggest precise answers.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you have a instance in the class and the value of a property for this instance is a String.

If so, do the following steps:

1. create OntModel and read file.

   ```
   OntModel ontModel = ModelFactory.createOntologyModel( OntModelSpec.XXX);
   ontModel.read(file:xxx);
   ```
2. get class and property:

   ```
   OntClass iClass =ontModel.getOntClass(className);
   OntProperty iProperty= ontModel.getOntProperty(propertyName);
   ```
3. get instance and output the string:

   ```
   for (ExtendedIterator<? extends OntResource> it= iClass.listInstances(true);it.hasNext();) {
       Individual ins = (Individual) it.next();

       RDFNode iValue = ins.getPropertyValue(iProperty);

       System.out.println(iValue.toString());
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

1. Load your ontology into an `OntModel`. I assume you did that already.
2. Use the `getProperty(String uri)` method of the `OntModel` to retrieve the property.
3. Use the `getOntClass(String uri)` method of the `OntModel` to retrieve the class. It returns an `OntClass`.
4. Use the `getPropertyValue(Property property)` method of the `OntClass` to get the value. It returns an `RDFNode`.
5. To turn the `RDFNode` into a string, either use simply `toString()`, or do `myRDFNode.asLiteral().getString()`.